# Is it true, that Creatine doesn't dissolve easily in our body?

Tags: creatine

Is is true that creatine doesn't get dissolved very easliy in our body ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creatine is very popular amongst those who want to improve their workout results. You can find creatine in red meat, but many people take it as supplement (e.g. in capsules). You probably already know that, if not dissolved properly, creatine won't be absorbed. For some people, it is true that creatine  doesn't dissolve easily, but there are some ways to resolve that problem. Drinking lots of water or grapejuice can help. Some people even put it in a coffee. Water and juice should be warm, too.